# How to mark/annotate some area from timeseries chart in achartengine

Tags: android, time-series, achartengine

I want to mark some area from the timeseries chart in the achartengine depending on the values I'm getting.

Current situation: 
I'm reading from a database and running a query there which supplies me with some data: (float valueX, float valueY, float valueZ, long timestamp, String annotation). Everything works fine and the chart is properly drawn. But I want to mark somehow the values when an annotation was read.

Here are two possibilities of what I'm trying to do:

[Variant 1](http://s14.directupload.net/images/130315/4jfjfs6o.png)

[Variant 2](http://s14.directupload.net/images/130315/o8szfprt.png)

Is this or something similar possible in the achartengine?

Answer (score 0):

There is an opened issue for something like this: http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=177

However, you could add a new series of data with some values defining the vertical lines or even some bars in order to highlight the regions.